# Crashing when calling indexPathForCell

Tags: ios, exception, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cells. Within each UITableViewCell, there is a UIButton. I'm attempting to find out which cell the button is located in when it  is tapped. To do this I've done this:

```
- (IBAction)likeTap:(id)sender {


UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
UITableViewCell *buttonCell = (UITableViewCell *)[senderButton superview];
UITableView* table = (UITableView *)[buttonCell superview];
NSIndexPath *pathOfTheCell = [table indexPathForCell:buttonCell];
NSInteger rowOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell row];
NSLog(@"rowofthecell %d", rowOfTheCell);
```

I thought this would work fine, but when indexPathForCell is called, an exception is thrown.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x756d650'
```

Any ideas about what I've done wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
(UITableViewCell *)[senderButton superview]
```

It should be:

```
(UITableViewCell *)[[senderButton superview] superview]
```

Because the superview of the button is not the cell, is the contentView which subview of the cell.

Comment: note: this will work on iOS7 but not in iOS6 !

Answer (score 2):

Why you dont set tag for each button in your cellForRowAtIndexPAth method:

```
button.tag = indexPath.row;
```

and then in your method you have:

```
- (IBAction)likeTap:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"rowofthecell %d", button.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use custom UITableViewCell and i have a crash too on ios7

On ios 6, it's work like a charm

```
UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
UITableView *table=(UITableView*)[cell superview];
NSIndexPath *path=[[sender superview] indexPathForCell:cell];
```

on ios7, this code above crash,

This code works on ios7 but i don't understand why...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
UITableView *table = [[(UITableView*)[cell superview] superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *path=[[sender superview] indexPathForCell:cell];
```

So i use edzio27 answer. I set a tag on my button.

Comment: Here is the the solution to work both on iOS6 & iOS7 http://stackoverflow.com/a/19651825/1294448

Answer (score 1):

Either you can set tag for each button as suggested by `edzio27` or you can try using `introspection` as shown below :

```
- (IBAction)likeTap:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    if ([senderButton.superView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        UITableViewCell *buttonCell = (UITableViewCell *)[senderButton superview];

        if ([buttonCell.superView isKindOfClass:[UITablewView class]]) {
            UITableView* table = (UITableView *)[buttonCell superview];

            NSIndexPath *pathOfTheCell = [table indexPathForCell:buttonCell];
            NSInteger rowOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell row];
            NSLog(@"rowofthecell %d", rowOfTheCell);
        }
    }           
}
```