# UITableViewCell indexPath crash in iOS7

Tags: uitableview, segue, ios7, superview

I've a `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableViewController`.
In my cell there is a button that when you click takes you to another `view` with a `prepareforsegue`.
In `prepareForSegue` I do this:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"])
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[sender superview] superview];
    UITableView *table = (UITableView*)[[[sender superview] superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForCell:cell]; 
}
```

Ok! Everything has always worked well. But now that I've upgraded xCode with iOS7, when I click on the button located in the cell, an error presents itself to me, and I don't know how to solve it:

```
[UITableViewCell indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e160b0
2013-09-20 16:30:44.427 MyApp[8212:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e160b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x024475e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01a5d8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x024e4903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0243790b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x024374ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   MyApp                              0x0004bc01 -[NewsTableViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 3441
    6   UIKit                               0x00af69cc -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 156
    7   UIKit                               0x00af6a59 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01a6f874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    9   UIKit                               0x005c4c8c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    10  UIKit                               0x005c4c18 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    11  UIKit                               0x006bc6d9 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    12  UIKit                               0x006bca9c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    13  UIKit                               0x006bbd4b -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    14  UIKit                               0x00936d7f _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7166
    15  UIKit                               0x00601d4a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
    16  UIKit                               0x00602c6a -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1030
    17  UIKit                               0x005d6a36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    18  UIKit                               0x005c0d9f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x023d08af __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x023d023b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x023ed30e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x023ecb33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x023ec94b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x032c89d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x032c87fe GSEventRun + 104
    26  UIKit                               0x005c394b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  MyApp                              0x00002cfb main + 235
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x01f42725 start + 0
    29  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The line where the app crashes is this:

```
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForCell:cell]; }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**In iOS7 `UITableViewWrapperView` is the superview of `UITableViewCell`**, which means another superview for you:

**iOS7:**

```
UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview.superview;
```

**iOS6"**

```
UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
```

Another change you can find it [here](http://www.curiousfind.com/blog/646):

seems your code:  UITableView *table = (UITableView*)[[[sender superview] superview] superview]; returns a `UITableViewCell` not a `UITableView`.

Try the below:

```
UITableView *table = (UITableView*)[[[[[sender superview] superview] superview] superview] superview];
```

Comment: In iOS 8 the view hierarchy seems to be like in iOS 6, so use the immediate superview again.

Answer (score 7):

Apple change the UITableViewCell hierarchy in iOS 7

Using iOS 6.1 SDK

```
<UITableViewCell>
   | <UITableViewCellContentView>
   |    | <UILabel>
```

Using iOS 7 SDK

```
<UITableViewCell>
   | <UITableViewCellScrollView>
   |    | <UITableViewCellContentView>
   |    |    | <UILabel>
```

So if you want to get indexpath at button index then use following code Using iOS 6 or later SDK

```
UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [book_table indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
    NSLog(@"index=%@",clickedButtonPath);
```

Using iOS 7 or 7+ SDK

```
UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview]superview];
    NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [book_table indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
    NSLog(@"index=%ld",(long)clickedButtonPath.item);
```

Answer (score 3):

It works for sure, but how super can we get?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem where I had to find the textFileds value from TableView

```
if ([Util isiOSVerGreaterThen7]) { // iOS 7
            UIView *contentView = (UIView *)[textField superview];
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superview];
            UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview.superview;
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

            NSInteger sectionOfTheCell = [indexPath section];
            NSInteger rowOfTheCell = [indexPath row];
        }
        else { // iOS 6
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[textField superview];
            UITableView *table = (UITableView *)[cell superview];
            NSIndexPath *pathOfTheCell = [table indexPathForCell:cell];
            NSInteger sectionOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell section];
            NSInteger rowOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell row];
        }
```

And Util is

```
+ (BOOL)isiOSVerGreaterThen7 {
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is better to use

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.callTable indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview]];
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way I think:

CGPoint subviewPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.myTable];

NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.myTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:subviewPosition];

You can simply get the index path here. Be it iOS7 or iOS6, it will return the correct index path