# Error message when launching my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector, nsexception

## EDIT : I found the solution, here is the answer :

[UITableViewCell indexPath crash in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919616/uitableviewcell-indexpath-crash-in-ios7)

Thanks !

I am using Xcode 5.1.1, on the simulator 7.0.
When I launch my application, I have an error that crashes my app.
Here is the error message :

```
2014-04-28 15:06:45.144 OpenSeriesMercedesFrance[7817:70b] -[UITableViewWrapperView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xadcce00
2014-04-28 15:06:45.146 OpenSeriesMercedesFrance[7817:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught  exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewWrapperView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xadcce00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x03a085e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02fbe8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x03aa5903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x039f890b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x039f84ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   OpenSeriesMercedesFrance            0x000524b2 +[Rules changeCell:atIndexPath:forRow:inSection:inFormDictionary:] + 354
6   OpenSeriesMercedesFrance            0x00051cdf +[Rules checkRule:atIndexPath:inFormDictionary:] + 911
7   OpenSeriesMercedesFrance            0x00154a8d -[MainViewController showFormScrollView] + 861
8   OpenSeriesMercedesFrance            0x00158986 -[MainViewController countrySelected:isDefaultCountry:] + 582
9   OpenSeriesMercedesFrance            0x00137055 -[CountryTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 565
10  UIKit                               0x00db77b1 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1513
11  UIKit                               0x00db7924 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 279
12  UIKit                               0x00dbb908 __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
13  UIKit                               0x00cf2183 ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
14  UIKit                               0x00cf212e _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
15  UIKit                               0x00cf1f5a _afterCACommitHandler + 532
16  CoreFoundation                      0x039d04ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
17  CoreFoundation                      0x039d041f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
18  CoreFoundation                      0x039ae344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
19  CoreFoundation                      0x039adac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
20  CoreFoundation                      0x039ad8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
21  GraphicsServices                    0x03c959e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
22  GraphicsServices                    0x03c95809 GSEventRun + 104
23  UIKit                               0x00cd5d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
24  OpenSeriesMercedesFrance            0x00029b7d main + 125
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0355a701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I don't really understand that message. When I check on other messages (when I google it, I find some people that has the same type of problems, and they say to look in the connection inspector. May be there is a button that has been removed, but I cannot see nothing...).

Comment: It looks like you have have the table view cell class wired-up as the tableview delegate and it doesn't respond to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: For information, that resolved my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919616/uitableviewcell-indexpath-crash-in-ios7

Comment: This resolve my problem :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919616/uitableviewcell-indexpath-crash-in-ios7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you set to be tableView delegate doesn't implement cellForRowAtIndexPath: method - which is required.

Try with default one (add this to your class where you create table):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks to be concerned with my problem :) The problem, is that I cannot see the UITableViewWrapperView...

Comment: Show the code of the class where you create UITableView

Comment: For information, that resolved my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919616/uitableviewcell-indexpath-crash-in-ios7

Answer (score 0):

Hello Grzegorz Krukowski,

Here is the UITableView.h as you asked me :

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewStyle) {
UITableViewStylePlain,                  
UITableViewStyleGrouped};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewScrollPosition) {
UITableViewScrollPositionNone,
UITableViewScrollPositionTop,    
UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle,   
UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
};                

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewRowAnimation) {
UITableViewRowAnimationFade,
UITableViewRowAnimationRight,           // slide in from right (or out to right)
UITableViewRowAnimationLeft,
UITableViewRowAnimationTop,
UITableViewRowAnimationBottom,
UITableViewRowAnimationNone,            // available in iOS 3.0
UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle,          // available in iOS 3.2.  attempts to keep cell 

centered in the space it will/did occupy
    UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic = 100  // available in iOS 5.0.  chooses an appropriate animation style for you
};

// Including this constant string in the array of strings returned by    sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: will cause a magnifying glass icon to be displayed at that location in the index.
// This should generally only be used as the first title in the index.
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UITableViewIndexSearch NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
// Returning this value from tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: or tableView:heightForFooterInSection: results in a height that fits the value returned from
// tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: or tableView:titleForFooterInSection: if the title is not nil.
UIKIT_EXTERN const CGFloat UITableViewAutomaticDimension NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);

@class UITableView;
@class UINib;
@protocol UITableViewDataSource;
@class UILongPressGestureRecognizer;
@class UITableViewHeaderFooterView;
@class UIRefreshControl;

//_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
// this represents the display and behaviour of the cells.

@protocol UITableViewDelegate<NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate>

@optional

// Display customization

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayFooterView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingFooterView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

// Variable height support

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;

// Use the estimatedHeight methods to quickly calcuate guessed values which will allow for fast load times of the table.
// If these methods are implemented, the above -tableView:heightForXXX calls will be deferred until views are ready to be displayed, so more expensive logic can be placed there.
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);

// Section header & footer information. Views are preferred over title should you decide to provide both

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;   // custom view for header. will be adjusted to default or specified header height
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;   // custom view for footer. will be adjusted to default or specified footer height

// Accessories (disclosures). 

- (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 3_0);
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

// Selection

// -tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath: is called when a touch comes down on a row. 
// Returning NO to that message halts the selection process and does not cause the currently selected row to lose its selected look while the touch is down.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

// Called before the user changes the selection. Return a new indexPath, or nil, to change the proposed selection.
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
// Called after the user changes the selection.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);

// Editing

// Allows customization of the editingStyle for a particular cell located at 'indexPath'. If not implemented, all editable cells will have UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete set for them when the table has editing property set to YES.
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);

// Controls whether the background is indented while editing.  If not implemented, the default is YES.  This is unrelated to the indentation level below.  This method only applies to grouped style table views.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

// The willBegin/didEnd methods are called whenever the 'editing' property is automatically changed by the table (allowing insert/delete/move). This is done by a swipe activating a single row
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

// Moving/reordering

// Allows customization of the target row for a particular row as it is being moved/reordered
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath;               

// Indentation

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; // return 'depth' of row for hierarchies

// Copy/Paste.  All three methods must be implemented by the delegate.

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);

@end

UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification;


//_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UITableView : UIScrollView <NSCoding>

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style;                // must specify style at creation. -initWithFrame: calls this with UITableViewStylePlain

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UITableViewStyle           style;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   id <UITableViewDataSource> dataSource;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   id <UITableViewDelegate>   delegate;
@property (nonatomic)          CGFloat                     rowHeight;             // will return the default value if unset
@property (nonatomic)          CGFloat                     sectionHeaderHeight;   // will return the default value if unset
@property (nonatomic)          CGFloat                     sectionFooterHeight;   // will return the default value if unset
@property (nonatomic)          CGFloat                     estimatedRowHeight NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0); // default is 0, which means there is no estimate
@property (nonatomic)          CGFloat                     estimatedSectionHeaderHeight NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0); // default is 0, which means there is no estimate
@property (nonatomic)          CGFloat                     estimatedSectionFooterHeight NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0); // default is 0, which means there is no estimate
@property (nonatomic)          UIEdgeInsets                separatorInset NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR; // allows customization of the frame of cell separators

@property(nonatomic, readwrite, retain) UIView *backgroundView NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_2); // the background view will be automatically resized to track the size of the table view.  this will be placed as a subview of the table view behind all cells and headers/footers.  default may be non-nil for some devices.

// Data

- (void)reloadData;                 // reloads everything from scratch. redisplays visible rows. because we only keep info about visible rows, this is cheap. will adjust offset if table shrinks
- (void)reloadSectionIndexTitles NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);   // reloads the index bar.

// Info

- (NSInteger)numberOfSections;
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

- (CGRect)rectForSection:(NSInteger)section;                                    // includes header, footer and all rows
- (CGRect)rectForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (CGRect)rectForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point;                         // returns nil if point is outside of any row in the table
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell;                      // returns nil if cell is not visible
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForRowsInRect:(CGRect)rect;                              // returns nil if rect not valid 

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;            // returns nil if cell is not visible or index path is out of range
- (NSArray *)visibleCells;
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows;
- (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)headerViewForSection:(NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)footerViewForSection:(NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;

// Row insertion/deletion/reloading.

- (void)beginUpdates;   // allow multiple insert/delete of rows and sections to be animated simultaneously. Nestable
- (void)endUpdates;     // only call insert/delete/reload calls or change the editing state inside an update block.  otherwise things like row count, etc. may be invalid.

- (void)insertSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
- (void)moveSection:(NSInteger)section toSection:(NSInteger)newSection NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);

- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
- (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);

// Editing. When set, rows show insert/delete/reorder controls based on data source queries

@property(nonatomic,getter=isEditing) BOOL editing;                             // default is NO. setting is not animated.
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated;

@property(nonatomic) BOOL allowsSelection NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);  // default is YES. Controls whether rows can be selected when not in editing mode
@property(nonatomic) BOOL allowsSelectionDuringEditing;                                     // default is NO. Controls whether rows can be selected when in editing mode
@property(nonatomic) BOOL allowsMultipleSelection NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);                 // default is NO. Controls whether multiple rows can be selected simultaneously
@property(nonatomic) BOOL allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);   // default is NO. Controls whether multiple rows can be selected simultaneously in editing mode

// Selection

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow;                                                // returns nil or index path representing section and row of selection.
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForSelectedRows NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0); // returns nil or a set of index paths representing the sections and rows of the selection.

// Selects and deselects rows. These methods will not call the delegate methods (-tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: or tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:), nor will it send out a notification.
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition;
- (void)deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated;

// Appearance

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount;                                                      // show special section index list on right when row count reaches this value. default is 0
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *sectionIndexColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;                   // color used for text of the section index
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *sectionIndexBackgroundColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;         // the background color of the section index while not being touched
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR; // the background color of the section index while it is being touched

@property(nonatomic) UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle separatorStyle;              // default is UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor               *separatorColor;              // default is the standard separator gray

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *tableHeaderView;                            // accessory view for above row content. default is nil. not to be confused with section header
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *tableFooterView;                            // accessory view below content. default is nil. not to be confused with section footer

- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;  // Used by the delegate to acquire an already allocated cell, in lieu of allocating a new one.
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // newer dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered
- (id)dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);  // like dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:, but for headers/footers

// Beginning in iOS 6, clients can register a nib or class for each cell.
// If all reuse identifiers are registered, use the newer -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: to guarantee that a cell instance is returned.
// Instances returned from the new dequeue method will also be properly sized when they are returned.
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (void)registerClass:(Class)aClass forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

@end

//_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
// this protocol represents the data model object. as such, it supplies no information about appearance (including the cells)

@protocol UITableViewDataSource<NSObject>

@required

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@optional

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;              // Default is 1 if not implemented

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;    // fixed font style. use custom view (UILabel) if you want something different
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;

// Editing

// Individual rows can opt out of having the -editing property set for them. If not implemented, all rows are assumed to be editable.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

// Moving/reordering

// Allows the reorder accessory view to optionally be shown for a particular row. By default, the reorder control will be shown only if the datasource implements -tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

// Index

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;                                                    // return list of section titles to display in section index view (e.g. "ABCD...Z#")
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index;  // tell table which section corresponds to section title/index (e.g. "B",1))

// Data manipulation - insert and delete support

// After a row has the minus or plus button invoked (based on the UITableViewCellEditingStyle for the cell), the dataSource must commit the change
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

// Data manipulation - reorder / moving support

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;

@end

//_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

// This category provides convenience methods to make it easier to use an NSIndexPath to represent a section and row
@interface NSIndexPath (UITableView)

+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRow:(NSInteger)row inSection:(NSInteger)section;

@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSInteger section;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSInteger row;

@end
```

Comment: For information, that resolved my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919616/uitableviewcell-indexpath-crash-in-ios7